# vertibird signals with all three factions

Tags: fallout-4

I've sided with the Minutemen for the end game and have managed to remain at peace with the Railroad and the BoS, but by doing so I've somehow failed the "Show No Mercy" quest which allows the vertibird signal grenades as a reward.

Is there a way to get vertibird signal grenades with the game in this state??

Answer (score 2):

*Yes*

The main quest line for the Minutemen will eventually allow you to acquire the Vertibird Signal Grenades.

> By completing the Minutemen questline, and upon destroying the Prydwen the player character will be given the grenade by Preston Garvey.

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vertibird_signal_grenade#Locations)

Comment: Is there anyway to get them with the brotherhood alive?

Comment: Did you read the spoiler?  Do you know the significance of that objective?

Comment: No idea, enlighten me? Why destroy them?

Comment: I dunno, the quest tells you.